# C++ QT4 detecting when a user double clickes a qtablewidget header

Tags: c++, qt4, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I am trying to detect when a user double clicks a header in a qtablewidget.  To do this I am connecting to the signal "sectionDoubleClicked(int)" to a function with the same arguments (i got this from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128539/qt-c-qtablewidget-doing-something-when-a-header-is-doubleclicked) ).  My issue is that I am getting the following compile time error:

```
mainwindow.cpp:117: error: no matching function for call to âMainWindow::connect(QHeaderView*, const char [27], MainWindow* const, const char [24])â
/usr/lib64/qt4/include/QtCore/qobject.h:181: note: candidates are: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const QObject*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType)
/usr/lib64/qt4/include/QtCore/qobject.h:282: note:                 bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) const
```

Here is my code:

```
QObject::connect(ui->table_results->horizontalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionDoubleClicked(int)),
              this,SIGNAL(headerclickedscan(int)));
```

do I just need to cast the result of horizontalHeader() to a QObject*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either didn't include QHeaderView by

```
#include <QHeaderView>
```

or didn't declare "headerclickedscan(int)" as signal in your MainWindow class.

Also are you sure you want "headerclickedscan(int)" to be a signal but not a slot ?

Comment: Your right, i ment to have slot not signal. fixed the issue. thanks.