# detecting header click in QTableWidget c++ qt4

Tags: c++, qt4, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget in my program that I use to display results and I am trying to be able to detect when a user single clicks one of the vertical headers.  To do this I am trying to connect the signal sectionDoubleClicked(int) to my function hheaderclicked(int).  When I try to compile the code I get a compile time error about no matching function.  I am basing my code from the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128539/qt-c-qtablewidget-doing-something-when-a-header-is-doubleclicked)

Compile Error:

```
mainwindow.cpp:138: error: no matching function for call to âMainWindow::connect(QHeaderView*, const char [27], MainWindow* const, const char [21])â
/usr/lib64/qt4/include/QtCore/qobject.h:181: note: candidates are: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const QObject*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType)
/usr/lib64/qt4/include/QtCore/qobject.h:282: note:                 bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) const
```

My Code:

```
QObject::connect(ui->table_results->horizontalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionDoubleClicked(int)),
              this,SLOT(hheaderclicked(int)));
```

Edit:
  I was able to get my code to work by doing the following:

```
QObject::connect((QObject*)ui->table_results->verticalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionClicked(int)),this,SLOT(hheaderclicked(int)));
```

Can some one explain why I had to cast QHeaderView* to QObject* to get this to work, i don't have to cast any of my other QObject::connect calls and they all work fine.  For example this work fine:

```
QObject::connect(ui->button_start,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(scanstart()));
```

is it because this one is connecting to a known object at compile time while my other one is connecting to a object that won't be known till runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives the third argument as `MainWindow* const`, which is rather odd. If it was `const MainWindow*`, the call should work. How is the calling function declared?

Comment: the connect is happening during construction of the mainwindow, MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent). is this the one you are asking about?

Comment: In view of your edit, is it possible that you forgot to #include <QHeaderView>?

Comment: I tried including <QHeaderView> per your suggestion and program now compiles with out casting to QObject*.  Thanks.